# Can't use the window.api properly

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am currently trying to create a borderless chrome app with a custom "control panel" for closing/minimizing/maximizing.

I have 3 divs (`#minimize`, `#maximize`, `#close`) that act as the buttons. I am trying to handle the clicks with javascript obviously. I have main.js included in my html header which has a the code I want.
As for closing the window my code looks like this:

```
document.querySelector('#close').onclick = function() {
  window.close();
}
```

That works like a charm.

As for maximizing the window I tried:

```
document.querySelector('#maximize').onclick = function() {
  window.maximize();
}
```

Which does not work. What did work was:

```
document.querySelector('#maximize').onclick = function() {
window.moveTo(0,0)
    window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);
}
```

I guess I am missing the obvious. `window.hide()` also does not work and it is also impossible to call other `AppWindow` functions such as `getBounds`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window object you are trying to manipulate is not Chrome's AppWindow. Use  `chrome.app.window.current().maximize()` etc.